# EPERM error by launching ember server in Windows

Tags: node.js, ember.js

I'm using ember 1.13.6 with node 0.12.7 and npm 2.13.2 on win32 x64. It happens frequently getting this error by executing "ember server" to launch server:

EPERM, operation not permitted 'C:\Project\my-app\tmp\core_object-output_path-UnoTIiak.tmp' other stuff ...

I have to terminate program and try again and again to succeed in launching server. When I edit my files and browser get refreshed, it happens again and I need terminate and launch server again. What is this issue?

Comment: Have you tried launching the server as an administrator?

Comment: I was just about to ask how you installed/setup npm (ie- as the root/admin user or as a non privileged user?)

Comment: @galactocalypse yes, I'm as the admin user.

Comment: @Toran Billups I installed as the admin user.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that since I have excluded my project folder in the Microsoft security essentials I get this error less than before.

Comment: This may not be feasible but you could consider moving the project to your user space/home directory.

Comment: This issue is driving me nuts under Windows 7 64 bit as well. As soon as I make a change to the app and ember rebuilds this error will be thrown and displayed. I'm running the console commands under administrator mode and have moved the project to my user folder as a test without any success.

Comment: It's a broccoli/node issue. I'm running as an admin user as well but it doesn't help. You don't have to terminate the program but to cause a rebuild enough many times by re-saving a file repeatedly. Seems like it's specific to 64-bit Windows (7/8?). The community is well aware of the problem. This issue likely has one of the most comprehensive root cause descriptions so far: https://github.com/broccolijs/broccoli/issues/39.